# ATOP Config file for an AWS Beanstalk deployment

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need ATOP to install on EC2 the instances when the machines deploy from Beanstalk. AWS support only had the link below to follow, but it doesn't show how to deploy in the ebextensions config files. Has someone already done this and have a config file already made? Thanks! --> https://www.tecmint.com/how-to-install-atop-to-monitor-logging-activity-of-linux-system-processes/
BTW using Amazon Linux

{{Edit 3/23/18}}

Working through this on my own so far, this is what I have. It doesn't fully work, but still working on it.

```
packages:
  rpm:
    epel: https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm

container_commands:
  1_rpm_atop:
    command: "sudo /bin/rpm -i --replacepkgs 
https://www.atoptool.nl/download/atop-2.3.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm"
  2_add_atop:
    command: "/sbin/chkconfig --add atop"
    leader_only: true
  3_add_atop:
    command: "/sbin/chkconfig atop on --level 235"
    leader_only: true
  4_config_atop:
    command: "/bin/sed 's/600/60/' /usr/share/atop/atop.daily -i"
    leader_only: true
  5_link:
    command: "/bin/ln -sfn /var/log/atop /var/app/current/wp-content/uploads/atop"
    leader_only: true
  6_start:
    command: "/etc/init.d/atop start"
    leader_only: true
```

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the amazing Yao from AWS Beanstalk tech support, we have been able to create a file that installs ATOP on all instances. As well, it writes individual instance logs to my already existing sym-linked EFS file directory so that the logs will persist through scaling and machine deployments. This is working now in my dev deployment. If you hear nothing else, it will mean that it is working in production as well in about a week. Here's the contents tweaked for my Wordpress deployment. Enjoy!

```
container_commands:
  1_install_config_atop:
    command: /tmp/installatop.sh

files:
  "/tmp/installatop.sh":
      mode: "000755"
      content : |
        #!/bin/bash

    #############################################


    ATOPLOGDEST=/var/app/current/wp-content/uploads/atop/   #where to persist the atop log
    LOGFILE=/tmp/atopinstall.log #installaton log

    ##############################################
    INSTANCEID=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id/)

    exec 1>&- # close stdout
    exec 2>&- # close stderr

    echo "========" >> $LOGFILE
    date >> $LOGFILE
    echo "starting" >> $LOGFILE

    echo "---- Step 1, install atop" >> $LOGFILE
    echo "check if atop is installed" >> $LOGFILE
    rpm -q atop >> $LOGFILE
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
      echo "atop not installed yet" >> $LOGFILE
      rpm -i https://www.atoptool.nl/download/atop-2.3.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
      rpm -q atop >> $LOGFILE
      echo "now installed" >> $LOGFILE
    fi

    echo "---- step 2, config atop in chkconfig" >> $LOGFILE
    /sbin/chkconfig --add atop
    /sbin/chkconfig atop on --level 235
    echo "this is the output of chkconfig"  >> $LOGFILE
    /sbin/chkconfig | grep atop >> $LOGFILE

    echo "---- setp 3, config atop's schedule to 60 seconds" >> $LOGFILE
    /bin/sed 's/600/60/' /usr/share/atop/atop.daily -i
    cat /usr/share/atop/atop.daily | grep "INTERVAL=" >> $LOGFILE

    echo "---- step 4, presistent it in EFS" >> $LOGFILE
    mkdir -p $ATOPLOGDEST$INSTANCEID
    /bin/sed "s|/var/log/atop|$ATOPLOGDEST$INSTANCEID|" /usr/share/atop/atop.daily -i
    cat /usr/share/atop/atop.daily | grep "LOGPATH=" >> $LOGFILE
    stat $ATOPLOGDEST$INSTANCEID >> $LOGFILE

    echo "---- step 5, restart atop" >> $LOGFILE
    /etc/init.d/atop restart
    sleep 5
    ps aux | grep atop >> $LOGFILE

    echo "---- finished!" >> $LOGFILE
    date >> $LOGFILE
    echo "========" >> $LOGFILE
```

Comment: Extra explanation - (there is) ... a CFN "bug"(eb deploy will invoke cfn-hup and cfn-init to run the container command), if the script involves installation an RPM package which starts the service, cfn-init will hang. It is a known issue and the workaround is to redirect STDOUT and STDERR to none in the beginning of the script [1]. ... This involves Python source code of cfn-init stored on ec2 instances. 
  Here is the workaround.
   exec 1>&- # close stdout
   exec 2>&- # close stderr

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
container_commands:
  1_add_epel:
    command:  sudo sed -i "6s,enabled=0,enabled=1,g" /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo 

  2_install_atop:
    command: sudo yum update && sudo yum install atop -y
```

Comment: As it turns out, epel was in conflict with a version that is included with the Amazon Linux version I am using, so it is unnecessary to install it. With Amazon's support help, we were able to get a working install. I am still testing the logging persistence on my symbolic link, but I will share the final config when done.